# Shopify discount and price rules access scopes. How to request them to Shopify? Where to get them to fetch discounts and price rule data?

Tags: rest, shopify, discount, scopes

I am trying to create app for my client. The client has website based on Shopify. I want to show the discounts the client has created on the website to show up on app. I went through Shopify API documentation but they mention nowhere how to get these accsess scopes for discounts and price rules. i was able to get orders and addresses access scopes but not for discount.
Where can I get these access scopes? OR how can I request these access scopes to Shopify.

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-01/resources/discountcode#get-price-rules-price-rule-id-discount-codes-discount-code-id

This is the URL for Shopify API documentation for discount codes. It clearly mentions that price_rule access scope is required.

Comment: you can price_rule documentation [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-01/resources/pricerule)

Comment: `read_price_rules`, `write_price_rules` are the scope that need to be have acess this enpoint.

Comment: @Onkar - Yes. I went through the documentation but I am not clear about how i can get these access scopes. It is not readily available on the SHopify Partners dashboard. Would request your help with that.

Comment: You are using the private app or creating a custom app or public app?

Comment: @Onkar - So, I am creating an ecommerce app for the client. The client already has their website on Shopify CMS. Our tech stack is different. We use ruby on rails for backend and react native for front end. We have added a Shopify Plugin for client to take a dump of products. Please let me know if any other information is required. And thank you for the help. :)

Comment: I am asking about the app type which you already created for your client, how the another scopes you got for your app currently?

Comment: They were available readily in the Shopify partners dashboard!